Why is the following system of functions linearly independent?
$2{i_1x}+2{i_2x}+⋯+2{i_nx}$ where all the numbers ${i_1},{i_2},…,{i_n}$ are different,
over R

I am just starting to study linear algebra and I have a question, why is this system linearly independent, if you can express $2^{i_2x}$ in $2^{i_1x}$


If we make all the coefficients zero, leave k = 1 for $2^{i1_x}$, and put k for $2^{i2_x}$, then we get $2^{i1_x}$ + k$2^{i2_x}$ = 0


k = -$2^{i1_x}/2^{i2_x}$ and k will never be 0


The problem is that $k$ must be a constant since the objects you are looking at are functions, so as a result $k$ cannot depend on $x$.
